# Kafka duplicate read

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using **Kafka version** `0.10.2.1` and **Spring boot** for my project.

I have 5 partitions of a topic which can be consumed by **multiple consumers** (having the **same Group-Id**) which are running on different machine.

**What Problem I am facing is** :

I am getting duplicate read of a single message with these Kafka warning logs

`Auto offset commit failed for group my-consumer-group: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.`

As logs indicate that this problem arises because Kafka consumer failed to commit.

Here are few details about my **use-case** :

- I have multiple consumers of a topic `My-Topic` that belongs to the same group-Id `my-consumer-group`
- Consumer consumes messages from Kafka, apply business logic and store processed data in `Cassandra`
- The process for consuming message from Kafka, applying business logic and then saving it to Cassandra **takes around 10 ms per message consumed from Kafka**.

I am using following code to create Kafka-consumer bean

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String brokerURL;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.session.timeout}")
    private int sessionTimeout;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.my-group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.listener.concurrency}")
    private int concurrency;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout}")
    private int timeout;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit}")
    private boolean autoCommit;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-commit-interval}")
    private String autoCommitInterval;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset}")
    private String autoOffsetReset;

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(timeout);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerURL);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommit);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, autoCommitInterval);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
        return propsMap;
    }
}
```

These are the kafka-configuration I am using

```
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=2
spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout=3000
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-commit-interval=1000
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=true
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.session.timeout=50000
spring.kafka.connection.timeout=10000
spring.kafka.topic.partition=5
spring.kafka.message.replication=2
```

My main concern is of duplicate read of a message by multiple Kafka consumers belonging to same consumer group and in my application, I have to avoid duplicate entry to the database.

Could you please help me and review my above Kafka configurations and Kafka-consumer-code so that I can avoid duplicate read.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is don't use `autoCommit` - it commits on a schedule.

Instead, let the container do the commits; using `AckMode` `RECORD`.

However you should still make your code idempotent - there is always a possibility of redelivery; it's just that the probability will be smaller with a more reliable commit strategy.

Comment: The problem is I have a counter column in Cassandra which gets incremented based on the message received by Kafka-consumer. 

If duplicate reads happen it will increment counter more than once which will result in wrong analytics.

Comment: Welcome to the world of messaging. For your scenario, "exactly once" delivery is impossible to achieve (google it if you don't believe me). As I said, you can minimize, but not eliminate, the probability of getting a duplicate delivery. Consider the case where you update mongodb and then the server crashes before you commit the kafka offset; result - redelivery. If it is critical, you have to check mongo first to see if you already stored this event.

Comment: Thank you @Gary. Your answer really helped me. If exactly once" delivery is impossible then how Bank and mission critical system works I know they use RDBMS but what messaging tool they use